# Vim : changing text between html tags

Tags: vim

I just wonder how to change the text between html tags right from the normal mode, like the way we can change text within double-quotes thanks to `ci"` ?

Answer (score 110, accepted):

For working between tags replace the `"` with a `t`, as in `cit`. Or `dit` to delete between tags and remain in command mode.

As you may already know, you can do `ci[`, `ci{`, or `ci(` to work between matched square or curly brackets, or parentheses. These commands also work with the closing character, so you can do `ci]`, `ci}`, or `ci)`.

Comment: See `:help text-objects` for a complete list.

Answer (score 50):

```
cit
```

Mnemonic: "Change Inner Tag" -- This obeys tag nesting, as well.